# No property or field 'Month' exists in type 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my code:

```
DateTime Tgl = Convert.ToDateTime(tgl.Text);
string SPKID = LibPNP.SPKID(r.Pers, "", "PO", Tgl.Month, Tgl.Year);
```

and I get this error:

> *No property or field 'Month' exists in type `DateTime`?*

How I can solve the problem?

Comment: What is thowing the error `LibPNP`, because DateTime certainly does contain `Month`

Answer (score 0):

Here you posted everything well. Probably you are having a typo in your code mixing `Tgl` and `tgl`:

You've got:

```
DateTime Tgl = ... //Tgl is DateTime
```

and some

```
tgl.Text //tgl (in lower case) some TextBox probably
```

I think in your code you have

```
//tgl - some TextBox, surely has no Month property
string SPKID = LibPNP.SPKID(r.Pers, "", "PO", tgl.Month, tgl.Year);
```

while it has to be

```
//Tgl - a DateTime
string SPKID = LibPNP.SPKID(r.Pers, "", "PO", Tgl.Month, Tgl.Year);
```

---